# subtractings arrays of ints in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, subtraction

I have two integer arrays of size 40. they are objects of the HugeInteger class. I need to subtract them. my code is

```
HugeInteger HugeInteger::subtract(HugeInteger other)
{
    int diff;
    HugeInteger result;
    for (int i=0; i<MAXDIGIT; i++)
    {

        diff=this ->myArray[i]-other.myArray[i];
        if (other.myArray[i] < this -> myArray[i])
        {
            result.myArray[i]=diff;
        }
        else
        {
            result.myArray[i]=other.myArray[i]-this->myArray[i];
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

The problem is the above code is not giving me the correct answer. I have checked it with a calculator, some of the digits are right and some are wrong. I think the problem may be how I am handling  the borrowing if subtraction would cause a number to be negative. can someone help me please? I have been trying to figure it out for 8 hours.

Comment: What is `HugeInteger`?

Comment: Is your `diff` wide enough to accommodate the subtraction result?

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you remove `diff` and calculate the result directly?

Comment: "the problem may be how I am handling the borrowing". rather, the problem is in you not handling the borrowing at all. To program this correctly, you need to recall how to do subtraction with paper and pencil, not with a calculator.

Comment: the problem still exists if calculation is done directly. HugeInteger is a class and the arrays are HugeInteger objects

Comment: Without knowing the type of `HugeInteger::myArray`, it's difficult to propose a real solution.  As others have pointed out, you're not handling the borrowing at all, so it's not surprising that the results are wrong.  You'll want to do the actual operation in a larger type than that of `HughArray`, if you can, and the base type of `HughArray` should probably be an unsigned integral type.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about "borrowing" but there's no such in the code.

The code,

```
HugeInteger HugeInteger::subtract(HugeInteger other)
{
    int diff;
    HugeInteger result;
    for (int i=0; i<MAXDIGIT; i++)
    {

        diff=this ->myArray[i]-other.myArray[i];
        if (other.myArray[i] < this -> myArray[i])
        {
            result.myArray[i]=diff;
        }
        else
        {
            result.myArray[i]=other.myArray[i]-this->myArray[i];
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

appears to compute the absolute value of each digit difference.

---

One way to do subtraction easily is to compute the N's complement of the number you'll be subtracting, then just add, where N is the base (radix) of your numeral system, and ignore any carry from the most significant digit.

E.g., to compute 55522 - 12345, first compute 99999 - 12345 = 87654, which is 9's complement for base 10, then add 1 to that, yielding 87655, the 10's complement, then just add, 55522 + 87655 = 143177, and ignore the carry, yielding 43177.

Checking: 43177 + 12345 = 55522, hurray, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `for loop` you should use this.

```
 if ((other.myArray[i]) < (this -> myArray[i]))
 {
     result.myArray[i] = this ->myArray[i] - other.myArray[i];
 }
 else
 {
    result.myArray[i] = other.myArray[i] - this->myArray[i];
 }
```

This will overcome the problem of `size` of `diff` variable.
Please check...

And yes do check if the `result` object is alive after finishing `substract` function code.
This also may cause problem. If so, Do create an object of `HugeInteger` class in the function and then `return` the same

Hope this will help you

Comment: This returns the wrong answer. The numbers are not right whenever subtraction would make it negative

Comment: @arisonu123 Can you please let me know the contents of the array? At least few of them.